# Rails select records with date bigger than or equal to nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a `Product` model with `expired_at` date field. I want query which return all products with `expired_at` value that bigger than some value or equals to nil.

But I met a troubles here:

```
manufactured_at = Date.tomorrow
Product.where('expired_at > ? OR expired_at = NULL', manufactured_at)
# => ActiveRecord::Relation []
Product.all
# => Product id: 1, expired_at: nil, Product id; 2, expired_at: nil, ...
```

How can I fetch these products in my query?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
manufactured_at = Date.tomorrow
Product.where("expired_at > ? OR expired_at IS NULL", manufactured_at)
```

try this